# Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked framework 'OpenTok.framework' was built for iOS with XCode 11.4

Tags: ios, ios13, opentok, xcode11.4

Problem - Error in iOS simulator
Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked framework 'OpenTok.framework' was built for iOS.

What percentage of your userbase does this affect (approximately)?
100%

List the steps to reproduce the problem.
just need to compile every-time, it will throw the same error

What is the expected output?
Source code should compile everytime

What OS and version are you seeing this problem with?
After migrating source code from XCode10.3 to XCode 11.4  we are facing this issue.

What OpenTok versions were you running (i.e. iOS SDK version, Android SDK version, JS version, etc)
OpenTok-iOS-2.10.0

Have you tested this on other computers and/or browsers? If so, what were your results.
Yes, whole iOS team is getting same issue

Work around we are doing to reduce this error is -  delete folder from code base and have a prebuild script to download open tok sdk folder again in source code, but it is taking lot of time when ever we are doing compile on simulator.
once you close and relaunch XCode 11.4 then also facing similar issue.

Comment: Have you tried removing opentok from pod file & install again?
I'm also using opentok in xcode 11.4

Comment: Do you get the same error when running on a physical device? But yes removing and installing the pod again should help

Comment: I have upgraded Opentok framework to latest version and that resolved my issues